# Is there any alternative for AllowsTransparency in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

We are facing some memory issues in our WPF Application. While searching for them I have found this particular MSDN link:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/framework/wpf-render-thread-failures

In this link, several ways are mentioned to resolve the memory issues and of them is this:-

> Disable the use of Windows.AllowsTransparency and
> Popup.AllowsTransparency in your application.

We tried the same but our popup starts appearing black from border area.

Is there any alternative way to show popup without setting AllowsTransparency property?

Comment: Share the exact memory issue and possibly code snippets triggering the error.

Comment: Without a minimal reproduction, your question is unsuitable for stack overflow.